# Unable to set object permission

Tags: object, access, custom-profile

As and admin I have cloned a profile and am trying to restrict the access of the new profile to only several objects.
First I want to remove the access to object "Financial goals".
I uncheck all the boxes from the Object permission table and click save.
The following error message pops up( the same happens when I do the same with a different object)
To me it looks like there are some dependencies that do not allow the removal of access.
Can you please help me what to do in this case?
Thank you

[image: error when saving changes]

Comment: Is Pricing Guidance a field? Did you look at the Field Level Security section?

Answer (score 0):

Error might be due to Winter '21 release updates for [CPQ and Advanced Approvals (AA)](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000354205&type=1), profiles are no longer able to grant access to any Salesforce Licensed Custom Objects (LCO) and permissions Licensed Custom Objects (LCO) and their related dependent objects.

The best practice to address this change is to remove any AA or CPQ permissions to licensed custom objects, including related dependent objects, from the profile.
Instead, assign permissions for these objects in a permission set and assign it to users.

Kindly follow below steps for profile editing tip:

- Temporarily disable 'Enhanced Profile User Interface' from Setup > User Management Settings > Disable “Enhanced Profile User Interface”.  This will allow to mass edit  profile CRUD actions from a single page.
- Ensure your profile doesn't have any CRUD permissions for the
  associated CPQ objects.